# Unable to set background image for a span/div in IE(8/9/10)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I tried using all the possible fixes, I could search. Including; checking of spaces, RGBa solution etc. But, nothing seems to work.

Please tell if there is any problem with the following

HTML:

```
<div class="viewReminders" title="View Reminder(s)">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
.viewReminders{
    background-image: url('viewReminders.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Your image might be larger than 16px...and check the height as well.

Comment: what is the `height`?

Comment: Here's a working fiddle everything seems to work correctly in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/CSnvs/1/  Granted im using a different image, is it possible your image is the same color as the background? Hence why you maybe not seeing it?

Comment: I am able to see it in Firefox...but not in IE. Your solution works fine. But what could be the problem with my image!?

Comment: Thank you all. It was a silly mistake. 

As you all suggested, the i matched the image size, and span size again. Added height as suggested by @stackErr. This works fine now. Everything is 16px now(width, heigth, image size).

Comment: Thank you all for your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.viewReminders{
    background-image: url('viewReminders.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You need to specify the height in your css.

Comment: IE doesn't treat a `&nbsp;` as content. So adding height to your CSS will resolve the issue.

Alternatively, you could add "View Reminders" and then set a negative margin of something outrageous (like -2000px) to "hide" the text ([css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) -- or any one of the other techniques on that site)

Comment: @San are you sure your url returns an image? Also is the image the same/similar color as your background?

Comment: yes, the url returns the image, and i am able to see the image in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to setting the height, as @stackErr suggested, you can use any number of the alternatives on [this post](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) at css-tricks.com.